# Angular ng-class isn't updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can someone help me understand why my `ng-click` doesn't update the class?

`heading.onClick()` updates the controller's `isOpen` attribute. When it is false, the class does not remove the `collapsed` attribute.

```
 .... (this is inside a controller aliased `heading`)
 <div ng-class="{'collapsed': !heading.isOpen}" ng-click="heading.onClick()"></div>


directive:
...
templateUrl: '/that/code/above',
controllerAs: 'heading',
controller: function(){
    var self = this;
    self.isOpen = false;
    self.onClick = function(){
        self.isOpen = !self.isOpen;
    };
}
```

Comment: "When it is false, the class does not remove the `collapsed` attribute" - that's because you have `!heading.isOpen`. typo?

Comment: I can't see your directive in use on div.. typo?

Comment: @UlukBiy, it was my understanding that the `<div>` was part of the directive's template

Comment: @NewDev you are right..

Comment: Please post a plunkr or jsfiddle.

Comment: shouldn't it be ng-style ?

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, there are just a couple things wrong.

1. Your quotes might need to be escaped since you are alternating
   between single and double a few times, or you might need to use template               instead of templateUrl
2. If you are using angular 1.3+, instead of assigning self to this you
   can use the scope: true property, and use 'this'.

```js
function myDirective() {
  return{
    restrict: 'AE',
    template: "<div ng-class='{\"collapsed\": !heading.isOpen}' ng-click='heading.onClick()'>Click on me</div>",
    scope: true,
    controller: function(){
                   this.isOpen = false;
                   this.onClick = function(){
                   this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
                        
                        // in some situations you might need to call $apply() to get it to digest changes.
                        // for example if you change isOpen through a non-angular click angular wouldn't know
                        // to update the class until you call this.$apply()
                        
                        //this.$apply();
                   };
      
    },
    controllerAs: 'heading'
      
    };
  }

var app = angular.module('app', [])
                 .directive('myDirective', [myDirective]);
```

```css
.collapsed {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">        
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
     <my-directive></my-directive>  
     
     <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
     <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In your case, you probably won't need to worry about this, but I have run across a scenario where I had to call $scope.$apply() (or this.$apply()) to notify angular that my variable has changed without its knowledge.